# Getting results with a primary key column showing null in my web-app, but the same SELECT statement in SQL Workbench works fine

Tags: mysql, null, doctrine, symfony-2.8, dbal

When I execute the following mySQLi query statement in mySQL Workbench, it works fine with all the rows having a non-null id values -- which is be because users.id is a primary key column, that may not contain nulls, and the outer join with artists returns rows from users, even if there isn't a related row in artists, but not the other way.

```
SELECT `users`.`id`,
       `users`.`username`,
       `users`.`id` AS 'users_id',
       `artists`.`id` AS 'artists_id',
       `artists`.*
  FROM `users` LEFT OUTER JOIN `artists`  ON `artists`.`users_id` = `users`.`id`
 WHERE IFNULL( `users`.`active`, -1 ) != 3
 ORDER BY `users`.`username`, `users`.`id`
```

However, when I run the same query in Sympfony v2.8 and Doctrine DBAL, using the following statement, several elements towards end of the array of the returned rows have null id values when I look at the contents of the $indexData array in XDebugger:

```
$indexData = $conn->fetchAll( $sqlStmnt );
```

Note, no errors are returned and both of the queries return 51 rows.

Comment: based on what you are stating, your logic is sound, users.id should never be null since it's on the left side of the outer join.  have you tried using the values itself to cross out the possibility of an xdebug bug?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately, I'm querying a table of unknown values and so I really can't use 'values itself', but I don't believe that this is a xdebugger but because running the query in my code returned the null, which is why I then ran the code in the debugger.  Lucky that I was able to rewrite the query as two queries, one for the 'in' and one for the 'not in' cases and then union the two cases together, which worked.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the SELECT query into two parts in order to remove the LEFT OUTER JOIN and then UNION'ed the two parts and applied the same sorting that I used in the original query, except that I had to use relative column order because UNION's do not allow sorting by source table column.  Note that the first part uses a user.id not in a sub-query on the artists table to eliminate rows that are found in part two.

```
(
  SELECT `users`.`id`,
         `users`.`username`,
         `users`.`id` AS 'users_id',
         `users`.*, NULL AS 'artists_id',
         NULL AS 'name',
         NULL AS 'artists_name_1st_char',
         NULL AS 'genre',
         NULL AS 'slug',
         NULL AS 'slug_count',
         NULL AS 'member_names',
         NULL AS 'background',
         NULL AS 'influences',
         NULL AS 'bio',
         NULL AS 'website',
         NULL AS 'instruments',
         NULL AS 'seeking',
         NULL AS 'youtube',
         NULL AS 'facebook',
         NULL AS 'instagram',
         NULL AS 'snapchat',
         NULL AS 'twitter'
    FROM `users`
   WHERE IFNULL( `users`.`active`, -1 ) != 3
     AND `users`.`id` not in ( SELECT `artists`.`users_id` FROM `artists`)
)
UNION ALL
(
  SELECT `users`.`id`,
         `users`.`username`,
         `users`.`id` AS 'users_id',
         `users`.*,
         `artists`.`id` AS 'artists_id',
         `artists`.`name` AS 'name',
         `artists`.`artists_name_1st_char` AS 'artists_name_1st_char',
         `artists`.`genre` AS 'genre',
         `artists`.`slug` AS 'slug',
         `artists`.`slug_count` AS 'slug_count',
         `artists`.`member_names` AS 'member_names',
         `artists`.`background` AS 'background',
         `artists`.`influences` AS 'influences',
         `artists`.`bio` AS 'bio',
         `artists`.`website` AS 'website',
         `artists`.`instruments` AS 'instruments',
         `artists`.`seeking` AS 'seeking',
         `artists`.`youtube` AS 'youtube',
         `artists`.`facebook` AS 'facebook',
         `artists`.`instagram` AS 'instagram',
         `artists`.`snapchat` AS 'snapchat',
         `artists`.`twitter` AS 'twitter'
    FROM `users` INNER JOIN `artists` ON `artists`.`users_id` = `users`.`id`
   WHERE IFNULL( `users`.`active`, -1 ) != 3
)
ORDER BY 2, 1
```

This query may actually be more efficient than the original query because it doesn't use a LEFT OUTER JOIN.  However, it can't use the artists.* to allow the query to get all of the columns in that table.  Instead, the columns in artists have to be explicitly named in the SELECT clause, so column changes in the artists table must be accounted for in this query.  For me it is only a small inconvenience.